# defining the i,j th entry of a matrix in loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix

Suppose I wanted to define an n x m matrix whose i,j th entry is i+j. How do I specify what I want the i,j th entry to be? In a 'for' loop, it doesn't let me say, for example, A[i,j]=i+j. How do I do this?

Comment: The easiest way is a list comprehension `[[i+j for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]`

Comment: Thanks, but I was also wondering how to change the i,j th entry of an existing matrix.

Comment: 'arrays' of nested lists are indexed by one index per bracket: `A[i][j]`

Comment: You should be able to do `a[i, j] = i+j` on a numpy array.  Could you share the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`np.fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html)** to define an `array` where `[i, j] == i + j`:

```
>>> np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i+j, (5, 5))
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

---

To change an element at position `[i, j]`, then you can just `index` it and change its value:

```
>>> a = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i+j, (5, 5))
>>> a[1, 2] = 99
>>> a
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  1.,   2.,  99.,   4.,   5.],
       [  2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

In `numpy` you could in principle create an empty array:

```
import numpy as np

m, n = 3, 5
A = np.empty(shape=(m, n), dtype=int)
```

and then fill it using a loop:

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        A[i, j] = i+j
```

That is, however, not the recommended way. Better avoid looping and take advantage of vectorization: Create a grid

```
i, j = np.ogrid[:m, :n]
```

and create your array in a single operation

```
A = i+j
```

In the special case of simply adding the indices you can do even shorter:

```
A = np.add.outer(range(m), range(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this `numpy` and since numpy is the correct way to handle large arrays and math in python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> i = 3; j = 4
>>> np.arange(i)[:,None] + np.arange(j)[None,:]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

#### To change an existing array

Let's create an array:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros((3,4))
>>> arr
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Now, let's change an entry:

```
>>> arr[1,2] = 1+2
>>> arr
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was also wondering how to change the i,j th entry of an existing matrix

Comment: @weedanorse See update for changing an entry in an existing matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is already created and thus an item already exists in row `i` and column `j` you can modify that item with

```
A[i][j] = newvalue
```

This works for the various "matrices" that are built in to Python, such as the list or array. Note that this means that each row in the matrix is a item in the overall list, so the "matrix" is really a list of lists.

Some other types that are added in other modules, such as `numpy`, also allow other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner:

```
arr = [[0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [0, 0, 0, 0],      
       [0, 0, 0, 0]] 

arr = [[i+j for j in range(4)] for i in range(3)]
```

Output:

```
arr => [
[0, 1, 2, 3], 
[1, 2, 3, 4], 
[2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

This changes the original array.